# How to convert from CST to PST?

Tags: php

How to convert this date

```
2010-05-25 04:55:01 CST (America/Chicago)
```

to `PST (America/Los_Angeles) timezone?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that (change the output format to suit your needs):

```
<?php
       $dte = new DateTime('2010-05-25 04:55:01', 
                  new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
       $dte->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
       echo $dte->format(DateTime::COOKIE);
?>
```

Outputs:

> Tuesday, 25-May-10 02:55:01 PDT

Comment: You can't give the timezone in the first argument of the DateTime constructor, otherwise the second argument gets ignored. I've removed the timezone abbreviation from the first argument and updated the output.